# Add duration to a date mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I try to learn to work with mongodb and nodejs and i have a problem.
I have a table in mongoDB called Schedule with fields id, start and end. For a specific row, I want to add to the start time a duration as long as the start time is lower than end.

Ex. I have the row in Schedule table:

```
{
   "_id": "123", 
   "start": "2020-03-11T09:00:00.000Z", 
   "end": "2020-03-11T18:00:00.000Z"
}
```

an duration parameter 30 minutes (30x60x1000ms). I want to obtain following result:

```
[
 {"id":1, "time":"2020-03-11T09:00:00.000Z"}, 
 {"id":2, "time":"2020-03-11T09:30:00.000Z"}, 
 {"id":3, "time":"2020-03-11T10:00:00.000Z"}, 
 {"id":4, "time":"2020-03-11T10:30:00.000Z"},   
 {"id":5, "time":"2020-03-11T11:00:00.000Z"},
 ...
 {"id":n, time:"2020-03-11T18:00:00.000Z}
]
```

I tried with $add aggregation, but i obtain just the first row.

```
const {idSchedule} = req.params;
const {duration} = req.body;
const durationMs = duration*60*1000;
console.log('duration',duration);
objId = new ObjectID(idSchedule); 
Schedule.aggregate([
   { "$match":{
        "_id": objId,
        }
    },
   { $project: { _id: 1, time: { $add: [ "$start", durationMs ] } } }
]).then((response) => {
    res.send(response)
})
```

And i obtain just:

```
[
 {
    "_id": "5e68ebf0992e173a28e7dd46",
    "time": "2020-03-11T09:30:00.000Z"
 }
]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one. The key operator is `$map: { input: { $range: ...`. First you have to calculate the size (I use `$let` for this) and then you can use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) to generate the array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         interval: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  size: {
                     $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$end", "$start"] }, { $multiply: [1000, 60] }]
                  }
               },
               in: {
                  $map: {
                     input: { $range: [0, { $add: ["$$size", 1] }, 30] },
                     in: {
                        id: { $add: [{ $divide: ["$$this", 30] }, 1] },
                        time: { $add: ["$start", { $multiply: [1000, 60, "$$this"] }] }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$interval" },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$interval" } }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0jJCKyBPyk6)

Comment: Hey Wernfried, thank you so much for your answer. It's work fine, but i receive 2 sets of data.   ex: ` [..{
        "id": 19,
        "time": "2020-03-11T18:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "time": "2020-03-11T09:45:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "time": "2020-03-11T10:15:00.000Z"
    }...]. I want to stop it after row with id 19. How can i do it? Thank you, again!

Comment: Most likely you have two documents in your collection. Put `{$match: {_id: "123"}}` at the beginning.